# Analytics events are not stored just real time

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I am tracking events for a WordPress plugin, using Google Analytics. The events are being reported in the live console, but not in the event history at any time window span. I have waited over a month to see if they show up, but no event is visible at the moment.

I have triple check my configuration and all looks as it is described in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference

This is the code used to report using php:

```
/**
 * Log an error / warning / info to Google Analytics
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @param string $message
 * @param string $type
 */
public function log_analytics( $title, $message, $type ) {
    $titan = TitanFramework::getInstance( 'airportdigital-settings' );
    $google_analytics_enabled = $titan->getOption( 'google_analytics_enabled' );
    if ( $google_analytics_enabled ) {
        $google_analytics_tid = $titan->getOption( 'google_analytics_tid' );
        $google_analytics_cid = $titan->getOption( 'google_analytics_cid' );
        $google_analytics_ec = $titan->getOption( 'google_analytics_ec' );
        $params = array(
            'v' => '1',
            't' => 'event',
            'tid' => $google_analytics_tid,
            'cid' => $google_analytics_cid,
            'ec' => $google_analytics_ec,
            'ea' => ucfirst( $type ),
            'el' => $message
        );
        wp_remote_post(
            'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect',
            array( 'body' => build_query( $params ) )
        );
    }
}
```

Any clue of what might be happening?

Comment: Are there any filters applied to your view? These filters could be excluding those hits from your final reports.

Comment: This may not be totally helpful but you should migrate to GTM asap. It ll help you a lot and comes with debugging features.

Comment: @vinoaj , nope there are any filters that apply. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Marco what do you refer to GMT?

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez Google Tag Manager

Comment: Alright I will try to go that way, thanks!